# get error HTTP Status 405 for rest web service POST method

Tags: spring

I load at browser as 
localhost:8080/picking/addPick get error HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported.

What wrong?Hope advice thanks

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/picking")

public class PickerController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ArrayList getAllPickingItems()throws SQLException,      ClassNotFoundException{
//....
}

@RequestMapping(value="/addPick",method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Boolean add(@RequestBody PickingInfo pickingInfo,HttpServletResponse response){
    try{
        Boolean success = pickerMethod.addPickingInfo(pickingInfo);
        response.setHeader("addPickingInfo", success+"");
        return true;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You limited URI`/picking/addPick` to POST requests :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addPick",method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

---

When you try to open that URI from your browser you're sending a GET request, not a POST. If you want to be able to access /picking/addPick from your browser you must either :

- remove the restriction `method=RequestMethod.POST`
- allow explicitely GET requests : `method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }`

If you just want to test a POST method, use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). Simply create a "New REST Project", paste your service URI, and send any type of HTTP Request you want.

Comment: My code above already have
@RequestMapping(value="/addPick",method=RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: yeah that's the problem : `RequestMethod.POST` ... when you try to open that URL from your browser you're sending a `GET` request, not a `POST`. If you want to be able to access /picking/addPick from your browser you must either remove the restriction `method=RequestMethod.POST` or allow explicitely GET requests : `method= { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }`

Comment: Oh,I see. Actually I just want to test the post method works or not.
Is there any way to do a simple test on my POST methods?

Comment: SoapUI has become the industry standard for testing SOAP & REST web services : http://www.soapui.org/. Simply create a "New REST Project", paste your service URI, and send any type of HTTP Request you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have mapped /addPick to the `add` method only for POST requests. Therefor GET is not mapped to anything (and in this case there is no point in mapping get to the method since you are also using `@RequestBody`)